# Encoding dec char instead of octal

Tags: encoding, char, decimal

I do not understand why

```
char test = '\032';
```

converts to

```
26 dec
```

`'\032'` seems to be interpreted as octal, but I want it to be treated as a decimal number.

I think I am confused with the character encoding.

> Can anybody clarify this for me and give me a hint on how to convert it the way I want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `'\octal-digit'` begins an *octal-escape-sequence*.  There is no *decimal-escape-sequence*.

Code could simply use:

```
  char test = 32;
```

---

To assign the value of 32 to a `char`, code has many options:

```
  // octal escape sequence
  char test1 = '\040';  // \ and then 1, 2 or 3 octal digits
  char test2 = '\40';

  // hexadecimal escape sequence
  char test3 = '\x20'; // \x and then 1 or more hexadecimal digits

  // integer decimal constant
  char test4 = 32;     // 1-9 and then 0 or more decimal digits

  // integer octal constant
  char test5 = 040;     // 0 and then 0 or more octal digits
  char test6 = 0040;
  char test7 = 00040;

  // integer hexadecimal constant
  char test8 = 0x20;   // 0x or 0X and then 1 or more hexadecimal digits
  char test9 = 0X20;

  // universal-character-name
  char testA = '\u0020';      // \u & 4 hex digits
  char testB = '\U00000020';  // \U & 8 hex digits

  // character constant
  char testC = ' ';   // When the character set is ASCII
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification, but i cannot change the escape octal sequence. It is part of a string that i am parsing. I somehow have to cast/convert it to get the decimal representation. Is this possible?

Comment: @user3482407 `char test = '\032';` and " It is part of a string that i am parsing." That means you are the compiler as compilers parse `char test = '\032';`.  Suggest amending post to show what you are really doing.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using (\0xxx) is for octal. To use decimal, you can just do:

```
char test = (char)32;
```